# req.body returns empty on post

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I'm pretty new to Express. not sure what I did wrong...
Here's a quick mockup of my situation.

app.js

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use('/static', express.static('./public'));

const urlEncoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
});

app.get('/form', (req, res) => {
  res.render('form');
});

app.post('/', urlEncoded, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`This app is listening on localhost:${port}`);
});
```

form.pug

```
block content
  form(action="/" method="post")
    label(for="name")
    input(for="name" id="name")

    input(type="submit")
```

the result in the console is an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing between id and name tag.The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted and this is what you are missing in your html form . So, just add a name attribute.

```html
block content
  form(action="/" method="post")
    label(for="name")
    input(for="name" id="name" name = "name")

    input(type="submit")
```

Comment: Thank you! how could I've missed that.